# Update status when overdue

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

I'm doing a small rental system where my SQL database will record the details of the product rented by the customer and an overdue date. if the date surpass the overdue date, the 'status' will be automatically set from "Currently Renting" to "Overdue". As of right now, this is what I could think of but of course, the logic is wrong from my codes. Please see the attached image as well for a clearer observation.

PHP

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "assignment3";



// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) 
{ 
die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$retrieve = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM rentproducts WHERE status = 'Currently Renting'");
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($retrieve);
$today = new DateTime(date("d-m-Y"));
$overduedate = new DateTime($row['overduedate']);
$overduedays = $overduedate->diff($today)->format("%a");
echo $overduedays;

if ($overduedays >= 1) 
{
    $sql = "UPDATE rentproducts SET status = 'Overdue' WHERE status = 'Currently Renting'";
    mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
}
?>
```

[image: SQL Database]

Comment: Did you have a question? Is this not working how you want it to? Please explain

Comment: Can't you simply do `UPDATE rentproducts SET status = 'Overdue' WHERE status = 'Currently Renting' AND overduedate - NOW() >= INTERVAL 1 DAY`?

Comment: @Dharman tried it, didnt work

Comment: You wouldn't normally store derived data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's true that your logic is wrong. Your `UPDATE` query will change all records from 'Currently Renting' to 'Overdue' regardless of the date.

If you want to set a value in SQL when the date is larger than another date (e.g. Yesterday) then you can use the SQL date functions. Use `NOW()` which will give you a date in DateTime format (i.e. Y-m-d H:i:s) or `CURDATE()` which will give you date in Date format (i.e. Y-m-d 00:00:00). Then you can add or subtract an interval.

```
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'user', 'password', 'test');
$mysqli->set_charset('utf8mb4'); // always set the charset

$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("UPDATE rentproducts 
    SET status = 'Overdue' 
    WHERE status = 'Currently Renting'
        AND overduedate >= CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 DAY");
$stmt->execute();
```

You could even set an event in MySQL to execute this query every day.

However, this is not a good database design. You are storing denormalized data. While sometimes it might make sense, I think that in this case you should leave the column `status` as it is, or even remove it altogether as it provides no extra information. Let your application deal with the status when it reads the data from the database.

For example:

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * 
    FROM rentproducts 
    WHERE status = 'Currently Renting'
        AND overduedate >= CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 DAY");
$stmt->execute();
$overdueRentals = $stmt->get_result()->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
```

Comment: In other words, get rid of the status column

Comment: @Strawberry I actually had that sentence in initial version of the answer but then I removed it. Let me add it back